# Block user from portal.azure.com

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My company is using Azure Active Directory. We are able to login into the Azure portal using AAD.

However, we only want a handful of employees to be able to login into the portal. All other employees should be kept out.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that if they are part of the AAD, you can however grant them no permissions, so they wont be able to see any resources or do anything on the portal

And you really dont have to do anything to acomplish that. Those are default permissions.

To check users permissions go to the portal and navigate to Azure AD blade.

Portal => AzureAd => Users => pick user => click Azure Resources on the left

Comment: As a test, I logged in using a regular employees account, and I was able to see everything and almost set up a virtual machine

Comment: this only means that this particular user has been granted access to resources in Azure. be default new users dont have access to resources in Azure. you should remove permissions from that user and he wont be able to access Azure resources.

Comment: I'm obviously a newb at this. I search around, but couldn't find an answer: How do I check the user's permissions to see what she has?

Comment: I checked the user's Azure Resources. It doesn't have any

Comment: If you go to Subscriptions, can you see anything? They won't be able to create anything or change anything unless you give them the rights.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the `Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal` setting, which will block all access unless a user has `Directory Reader` or higher permissions in Azure AD

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions

As a Global admin:

- Azure Active Directory
- User Settings
- Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal -> yes

Answer (score -1):

Or you can just block sign in for the user in the user profile. By this, the blocked users will be denied to log in the portal.

[image]

Note: This operation requires the global admin.

Comment: If there is anything to update please let me know, thanks!

Comment: I have about 10 people in the company that I would like to have access. The rest of the 250 employees, I would like to block. Is there a way to do a group block, or would I have to block all 240 individually?

Comment: @Chris, as I know, you cannot block user sign in via group in the Azure portal. And I also tried other methods, like graph API, cannot find batch operation about the user or group.

Comment: Blocking sign in prevents a user to sign in to any resource, so a user won't be able to login to Office 365 as well.